# excel remove duplicates with columns array as a variable

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The following code doesn't remove the rows that are duplicates - Type Mismatch Error.  I have the complication that I dont know how many columns there is.  Please could someone tell me what I have done wrong. Thank you

```
    ReDim myarray(endcol - 2)
    For echarrayval = 1 To endcol - 1
        myarray(echarrayval - 1) = eacharracycol
    Next echarrayval
    remduprng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(botrw, endcol - 1)).Address
    ActiveSheet.Range(remduprng).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(myarray), Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: On which line do you get the Type Mismatch Error? There are many variables whose validity is impossible to check with the provided code sample.